# How do I convert a folder of static html files to be served by node/express through jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a folder of static html files files as part of an existing project. I would like to find the simplest way to serve these via node/express using jade. There is a common head/menu/header section at the top that I would like to strip out and put in the jade template, a common section of js includes at the bottom that should also be in the template, and I would like to send a couple variables (e.g.  the user) from the server. I would very much appreciate a pattern of how to do this that shows:

- the route and controller for the render and how to set up the corresponding static serving with node
- the sections of content in the jade files
- where the static files should be stored
- how jade links together blocks with the same class/id.

Thank you.

Comment: http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

Comment: OR a node package: https://github.com/donpark/html2jade

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I could just pull in the html into the jade file, but the solutions you suggest are both reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the static files with `fs` and then pass the `data` of each file through `res.render('page', {contentHTML: data})`. In the client page use the `!=` operator to unescape the data and inject it to the view.

For example:

static.html (suppose that the file is in the `views` folder)

```
<div>
  <p> some text </p>
</div>
```

Server: (suppose this code is in the `routes` folder)

```
router.get('/static', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('./views/static.html', function(err, data){
        res.render('page', {responseHtml: data});
    });
});
```

page.jade: (suppose this view is in the `views` folder)

```
extends layout

block content
  div!= responseHtml
```

The app structure is this:

```
-example
  ...
  -routes
     index.js (here is the code show above, in the Server section)
     users.js
  -views
     ...
     page.jade (client code show above)
     static.html (content to load in page.jade)
  app.js
  package.json
```